# When waking up this computer blue wierd face characters appeared

Tags: 18.04, suspend, 32-bit, lts, wakeup

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-62-generic i686) and each time the computer lid is closed it goes to sleep and then wakes the screen displays this and it is unresponsive.
I have since disabled the sleep function when the lid is closed and keep it logged in to stop it from coming unresponsive.
It is quite old hardware:

- CPU: mobile AMD Athlon XP-M 2400+ @ 1.79126GHz
- GPU: ProSavage8 KM266/KL266
- RAM: 51MiB / 394MiB

It runs without a Desktop Environment in terminal mode most of the time.
It has LXDE Desktop Environment installed (the hardware can't handle any more intensive).
The problem I have is that I can't put it to sleep so I either have to have it on (and it is quite loud) or off (it takes a few minutes to boot). I would love to be able to put it to sleep every so often.
I have super user privileges, current access (through ssh) and I know how to use the terminal quite well.

[image]
Cropped image showing the faces here:
[image]